# How to make disabled state of font awesome icon button?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am using font awesome icon button and I need to have a disabled state of the icon. I am able to make it look like disabled button using Bootstrap disabled class but it's clickable.
Is there any way to make is non-clickable ?

Here is my HTML code:--

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class='btn btn-primary disabled' disabled>
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: you already have a `disabled` tag on the <button>, how can it still be clickable?

Comment: Icon is clickable, if I don't use font-icons then it is not clickable.

Comment: @user8053092 you must be mistaken, `[disabled]` attribute works in both conditions see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54177198/2813224)

Comment: @zer00ne yeah I got it, but click on your last button(enabled) then click on the disabled button(just on the icon), active state of the enabled button is gone.

Comment: @user8053092 yes that's how it always works, `:active` only lasts until user releases the mouse button. What you are seeing is `focus` and that's the correct behavior as well.

Comment: @user8053092 okay now I understand see [update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54177198/2813224)

Answer (score 6):

use `pointer-events: none;`

```css
button{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class='btn btn-primary disabled' disabled>
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

## `.focus()`, `trigger()`, & `.blur()`

After clarifying what OP really wanted: ***to keep `button.disabled` from stealing `focus` from enabled buttons. Updated demo does that but not to `button[disabled]` those are truely dead to the world.

### `[disabled]` Attribute Always Works

`[disabled]` attribute works. Bootstrap `.disabled` class does not. See the tests in demo below.

### Demo

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('clicked')
});


$('.btn').not('.disabled').on('click', function() {
  $('.btn').removeClass('lastFocus');
  $(this).addClass('lastFocus');
});

$('.disabled').on('focus', function(e) {
  $(this).blur();
  $('.lastFocus').trigger('focus');
});
```

```css
b {
  color: cyan
}

u {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class='btn btn-primary' disabled>
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i><b>[disabled] attribute</b>
</button>

<button class='btn btn-primary disabled' disabled>
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i><b>[disabled] attribute</b> and <u>.disabled class</u>
</button>

<button class='btn btn-primary disabled'>
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i><u>.disabled class</u>
</button>

<button class='btn btn-primary disabled'>
  <u>.disabled class</u>
</button>

<button class='btn btn-primary'>
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>enabled
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```html
   

 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <button class='btn btn-primary disabled' disabled style="pointer-events:none">
      <i class="fa fa-search" ></i>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try in this way also.

```css
.xyz
        {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        pointer-events: none;
        color: #c0c0c0;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        }
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class='btn btn-primary xyz'>
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked using pointer-events on icon.

Here is my answer:-

```html
<button class='btn btn-primary disabled' disabled>
    <i class="fa fa-search" style="pointer-events:none"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `onclick="return false;"` to make sure it won't fire click event.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class='btn btn-primary disabled' onclick="return false;" disabled >
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```